# How to get correct datagridview valid row/column index in MDIParent in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mdiparent

I have a datagridview on a form which when I click, gives me the correct row/column index clicked: 
[image]

Clicking on verify [third column, first row, gives the above].
But when this form is called from an MDI parent, clicking on thesame column three, row one (Verify) gives this:
[image]

Below is the behind code for the form:

```
var result = new DAO().RetrieveAllProjects().Select(r => new { r.Name }).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btn.HeaderText = "";
btn.Text = "View/Edit";
btn.Name = "edit";
btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

DataGridViewButtonColumn btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btn2.HeaderText = "";
btn2.Text = "Verify";
btn2.Name = "verify";
btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn2);

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 290;
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
dataGridView1.CellClick += dataGridView1_CellClick;

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ColumnIndex:{0}, RowIndex: {1}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex));        
}
```

And it's called from the mdi parent this way:

```
projectsListForm pLF = new projectsListForm();
pLF.MdiParent = this;
pLF.Show();
```

How can I make sure that the correct row/column is highlighted on the mdi parent

Comment: Is there some reason you have to set the parent form as a `MdiParent` as this seems to be the problem with the column indexing in the child form. Why the indexing is incorrect, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason[s] when MdiParent is used, two round of databinding happens in dataGridView1 (DataGridView `DataBindingComplete` event is triggered). "Name" column gets unnecessary removed and added (DataGridView `ColumnAdded` and `ColumnRemoved` events). To stop this behavior I disabled columns auto-generation after seting DataSource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ...;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

A safer option is to work with columns by names, not by indices